# Get list of file fron regex

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to do a bash script that extract info from pdf documents. the first argument should be a regex or the name of a file. Es:

```
$ autobib shrek2001.pdf
$ autobib *.pdf
```

My idea is to generate a list of files matching the regex and extract information from them. My code at the moment looks like this:

```
for article in $(ls $1);do
    pdfinfo $article
done
```

But doing so the loop stops at the first file. How can I loop over all the files matching my regex?

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (there is a reason that is Pit Fall No. 1) -- much less an unquoted `$1` in the *command substitution* and an unquoted `$article` as the argument to `pdfinfo`.

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net

Comment: i corrected using your suggestion: `for file in ./*.pdf; do pdfinfo "$file" ; done` but if I execute this line of code in my terminal everything works, while if I execute a bash script it prints only the first file

Comment: You have windows line endings, aka carriage return in the script. Hint, windows notepad editor does that by default.

Comment: I'm usiong vim actually. The problem seems that if I give as a first argument a regex then $1, $2,$3, etc.. are names of files

Comment: You need to debug, add `set -x` after the shebang and run your script.

Comment: ```*.pdf``` is not a regex, it's a glob. Bash expands it to a list of arguments. You can rely on this behavior and use ```for article in "$@"; do pdfinfo "$article"; done```. Or you can quote the glob argument and leave ```$1``` unquoted so that bash does not expand it until the for loop. ```./autobib '*.pdf'``` ```for article in $1; do pdfinfo "$article"; done```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clpgr has it completely right.  Change your program to look like this:

```
for article in "$@" ;do
    pdfinfo $article
done
```

The reason your program only does the first file is that the shell command gets globbed.  That is, when you issue the command `autobib *.pdf`, you are really issuing this command:  `autobib 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf` (well, I'm making up some file names since I don't know what's in the directory.  But the point is, your program will have $1 set to 1.pdf so you'll be executing this code `$( ls 1.pdf )` which would only return 1.pdf.

Truth is, your program may have worked (depending on the file names in the directory) if you executed this way:  `autobib "*.pdf"`.  In this example, the "*.pdf" is not globbed by the shell because it is quoted.  Now, your program's $1 variable will have the value `*.pdf`.

That said, `"$@"` is soooooo much better than `$( ls $1 )`.  `"$@"` will actually preserve spaces in the arguments.